# Invitation email when granting permissions in SharePoint 2013 is not sent

Tags: 2013, domain, smtp

When I grant permissions to some user under the same domain than I am.

They do not recieve email even if I check "send invitation"

SMTP configuration is set. All the other notifications are working Alerts, forms etc.

Can someone help me with this problem ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem today. It seems the user must have the permission to manage permissions. After I changed the permission level that was mapped to the user and he added a user to a group, the invitation email was send. Without the right to manage permissions, no email was send.